# Python Pandas - Calculate total mean, group by field, then calculate grouped means and append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pd.DataFrame with the columns "dir" and "speed":

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dir': ['fwd', 'fwd', 'fwd', 'bwd', 'bwd'],
                  'speed': [10, 5, 1, 6, 8]})

# or with more columns:
df = pd.DataFrame({'dir': ['fwd', 'fwd', 'fwd', 'bwd', 'bwd'],
                  'speed': [10, 5, 1, 6, 8],
                  'mass': [100, 200, 100, 500, 300]})
```

```
   dir  speed

0  fwd     10

1  fwd      5

2  fwd      1

3  bwd      6

4  bwd      8
```

I'm trying to calculate 3 things, with the result being a DataFrame with 1 row, containing "median_speed", "median_fwd_speed", "median_bwd_speed".

I'm really new to Pandas so forgive my horrible upcoming mistakes. Also, I have a lot of other stuff being calculated, so keeping agg is definitely preferable, but doing away with np.where() would be great.

What I have so far:

```
# duplicate dir column for future referencing
df['dir2'] = df['dir']

# groupby and calc median for fwd and bwd
df = df.groupby('dir').agg({"dir2": lambda x: x.iloc[0], # how do I do nothing with agg?
                            "speed": "median"})

# grab forward and bwd fields
df['median_fwd_speed'] = np.where(df['dir2'] == 'fwd', df['speed'], 0)
df['median_bwd_speed'] = np.where(df['dir2'] == 'bwd', df['speed'], 0)
```

Output:

```
    dir2  speed  median_fwd_speed  median_bwd_speed

dir                                                

bwd  bwd    7.0               0.0               7.0

fwd  fwd    5.0               5.0               0.0
```

Of course the output is not 1 row, and doesn't contain the total median. Any help would be appreciated!

I could probably use `df["speed"].median()` and store it as a variable, but is there an elegant way using just groupby and agg?

Expected output with multiple columns would be something like:

```
median_speed    fwd_median_speed    bwd_median_speed    median_mass    fwd_median_mass    bwd_median_mass
6               5                   7                   200            100                400
```

Comment: Can yo add expected ouput from multiple columns sample data?

Comment: @jezrael Added to the end of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate `median` and then add new column for `median`:

```
f = lambda x: f'median_{x}_speed'  
df1=df.groupby('dir')[['speed']].median().rename(f).T.assign(median = df['speed'].median())
print (df1)
dir    median_bwd_speed  median_fwd_speed  median
speed                 7                 5     6.0
```

EDIT: For multiple columns use:

```
cols = ['speed', 'mass']
df1=(df.groupby('dir')[cols]
       .median()
       .T
       .assign(median = df[cols].median())
       .stack()
       .to_frame()
       .T 
       )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
print (df1)
   bwd_speed  fwd_speed  median_speed  bwd_mass  fwd_mass  median_mass
0        7.0        5.0           6.0     400.0     100.0        200.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I actually have multiple columns, hence the use of agg, how shall I incorporate this into your solution? I have added an example to the question with a new 'mass' column

Comment: @Frankfurters - answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
(df.groupby('dir')['speed']
    .agg('median')
    .append(pd.Series(index = ['total'], data = df['speed'].median()))
    .to_frame()
    .T
)
```

output:

```
    bwd fwd total
0   7.0 5.0 6.0
```

you can further rename columns if you want using `.rename(columns = ...)` method

### Edit

with multiple columns this should work

```
(df.groupby('dir')
    .agg('median')
    .append(df.median().rename('total') )
    .unstack()
    .to_frame()
    .T
)
```

output

```
    speed           mass
dir bwd fwd total   bwd fwd     total
0   7.0 5.0 6.0 400.0   100.0   200.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I actually have multiple columns, hence the use of agg, how shall I incorporate this into your solution? I have added an example to the question with a new 'mass' column

Comment: edited -- pls take a look

Comment: Looks great! I used `df.columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` to rename the columns and remove the stacked column names. It also gives me a deprecated warning: `FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.` Quoting `.append(df.median().rename('total'))`

Comment: not sdure where it is coming from -- I am not getting that. would not worry about it. But a more canonical way to rename columns is using `.rename` function as in @jezrael answer

Answer (score 0):

I would extract each value, place it in a list and convert the list to a DataFrame so the values are represented in a single row.

```
metrics = [
    df[df['dir'=='fwd']]['speed'].median()
    df[df['dir'=='bwd']]['speed'].median()
    df['speed'].median()
]

pd.DataFrame([metrics], columns=['median_fwd', 'median_bwd', 'median_speed'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately I have a lot of values being calculated, and manually typing these statements for the ~50 of them is probably not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a separate dataframe to hold the result. You can get the medians in two operations: a direct median, and a median on the groupby:

```
pd.DataFrame([[df['speed'].median(), *df.groupby('dir')['speed'].median()]],
             columns=['median_speed', 'median_bwd_speed', 'median_fwd_speed'])
```

With more columns you could do

```
cols = ['speed', 'mass']
pd.DataFrame([[*df[cols].median(), *np.ravel(df.groupby('dir')[cols].median())]],
             columns=[f'median_{i}{j}' for i in ['', 'fwd_', 'bwd_'] for j in cols])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I actually have multiple columns, hence the use of agg, how shall I incorporate this into your solution? I have added an example to the question with a new 'mass' column

Comment: @Frankfurters. You would just add `mass` to the columns